# Sed, remove all comments in a file

Tags: sed

I have a sed command that removes comments in a file as,

```
sed -i /^#/d /path/to/file
```

This works but not when the comments are indented/have a preceding space.

like

```
#this is a good comment           ---- works
    #this is an indented comment  ---- doesn't work
```

How can i change it to remove lines that has # as the first visible character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify your regex so that it allows for leading whitespace.

```
sed -e '/^[ \t]*#/d'
```

This regex will match lines beginning with 0 or more spaces or tabs (in any order), followed by a hash sign.

GNU sed also supports symbolic names:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*/d'
```

Which includes all whitespace characters, including the funny unicode foreign language ones. That's less portable, however.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed -i -e '/^[ \t]*#/d' /path/to/file
```

You might have to replace \t by a literal tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d' file.txt
```

Using `grep` :

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*#' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sed '/^\s*#/d'
```

Explanation:

```
^ beginning of line
\s* arbitrary amount of whitespace (or none)
```